# Why cant I read using fscanf after an error?

Tags: c, scanf

I am reading information from a file.The file consists of format

```
5
3 4 5 6
5 6 a 8 9 2
3 9 42 51 32
67 53 43
5 6 7 8 9 2
```

Line 1 contains number of Testcases N
Next N line will contain integers delimited by space.
Now my desired output is

```
18
Invalid Input
137
163
37
```

For each testcases the output consists of a single integer which corresponds to addition.
I had given the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int flag=0,total=0,r=0,n,i,value,x;
   char filename[100],c;
   scanf("%s",filename);
   fp=fopen(filename,"r");
   fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       total=0;
       flag=0;
       do
    {
        r=fscanf(fp,"%d%c",&value,&c);
        if(r!=2)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid Input");
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
        else
            total+=value;
    }while(c!='\n');
    if(flag!=1)
    {
       printf("\n%d",total);
    }
}
}
```

but since we cant read with fscanf after an error I cant read the entire input.And I am getting the output

```
18
Invalid Input
Invalid Input
Invalid Input
Invalid Input
```

So what can I do to get the required output

Comment: The non-matching character stays in the input stream until it is read. As you only ever read numbers, you never remove it from the input stream. You could just read one character with `getchar` and try again, [see here](http://ideone.com/xJ5iNT).

Comment: I had tried but I am using fscanf but not scanf.Its not working.Please help me

Comment: You could use fscanf with %c, as in the answer below, or `fread(fp, dummy, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

When `scanf` reaches the spot with an invalid character `'a'` it tries to read it with `%d` format specifier. Since this does not work, `scanf` leaves `'a'` in the buffer, and returns `0` for the number of items read from the input.

Since your code tries reading `%d` again, nothing happens: the buffer stays where it was before the read, with `'a'` as the next character. This continues until the count `n` is exhausted.

Fix this problem by adding code that reads from the input until it reaches `'\n'` or `EOF` after the inner loop is exited:

```
do {
    ... // This is your reading loop
} while (c != '\n');
// We can reach this line either because `c` is `'\n'`, or because of an error
// If we are here due to an error, read until the next `'\n'`
while (c != '\n') {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%c", &c) == 0) {
        break; // We are at the end of file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your input may contain things other than integers, you ideally should read characters (or rather character arrays, strings). You then try to convert these to integers and report any conversion errors.

Conversion from a string to integer (`long`) may be done using `strtol()` which is defined in `stdlib.h`. There's also an `atoi()` function which is easier to use, but that doesn't provide any way of checking that the conversion was successful.

`strtol()` has the prototype

```
 long strtol(const char *restrict str, char **restrict endptr, int base);
```

`str` is your string, `base` is the base (duh), i.e. 10, and `endptr` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` that the routine will set to the first character *not* converted.

The conversion is successful if `*str != '\0'` and `*endptr == '\0'`.